# PowerShell Import-CSV to Export-CSV with type conversion

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I get a bunch of tab-delimited files and I want to convert them to comma-delimited files. I also need only two columns from the file "Date" and "Value1", so I drop the rest of the columns.

```
Date    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Sensor
08.07.2010  115,28  115,45  115,45  115,28  100
07.07.2010  115,34  115,32  115,34  115,25  85
06.07.2010  115,23  115,74  115,74  115,20  203
```

This works as follows:

```
(get-ChildItem -Path '*.txt').name | ForEach-Object { 
    Import-Csv -Path $_ -Delimiter "`t" | 
    Select-Object -Property Date,Value1 | 
    Export-Csv "out\$_" 
}
```

Unfortunately in the source file **a comma is used as decimal separator**. So I get these files where Value1 is interpreted as string:

```
"Date","Value1"
"24.02.2017","30,18"
"23.02.2017","30,20"
"22.02.2017","30,18"
"21.02.2017","30,18"
"20.02.2017","30,17"
```

How can I set the data type of the column to numeric? During `Import-CSV`?

Comment: can you share the initial CSV?

Comment: Added. I had some issues inserting the tabs ... but now it seems to displays correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**`Export-CSV` *always* adding `"..."` around the output field values is *not* (in itself) a problem:**

- **The CSV data format has *no* intrinsic concept of a *data type***, and **double-quoting is solely used to *enclose* a field value** (which is a syntactical requirement for field values with embedded `,` chars., for instance).
- **Excel, for instance, *infers* a column's data type solely from its *content***, whether that content is enclosed in double quotes or not.

  - The **content interpretation is *culture-aware (locale-aware)***, however.
- By contrast, **PowerShell's `Import-Csv`** ***never* interprets the data and returns all field values as *strings***.

Depending on *the active culture in the environment the CSV will be processed in*, you have two options:

- For a culture such as `de-DE` (Germany) in which `,` (comma) rather than `.` (dot, period) is used as the decimal mark, and `;` rather than `,` is used as the list separator:

  - With the target culture in effect (verify with `Get-Culture`) use `Export-Csv -UseCulture`
    (`-UseCulture` is available since (at least) v2<sup>[1]</sup>
    ).<sup>Thanks, [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings)</sup>
  - Alternatively, use something like `Export-Csv -Delimiter ([cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('de-DE').TextInfo.ListSeparator)`
- For an **English-language culture** (or any other culture that use `.` as the decimal mark):

  - **Custom-process the file** and **replace the `,` instances in numeric fields with `.`** - see below.

---

To replace the `,` instances with `.`, the following command, which uses string manipulation only, will do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *.txt | ForEach-Object {
  Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ -split '\t')[0,1] -replace ',', '.' -join ','
  } |
    Set-Content -Encoding utf8 "out/$($_.Name)"
}
```

Note: For simplicity, the command assumes that the `Date` column values contain no instances of `,` and that none of the values require `"..."`-enclosing - which is reasonable in this specific scenario.

- I've chosen UTF-8 as the output encoding above, because `Set-Content` defaults to the legacy, culture-specific "ANSI" code page - adjust as needed.

---

<sup>[1] Generally, if a parameter description in a cmdlet's help topic doesn't mention a specific version in which it was introduced, it implies that it's been around since v2. You can now **browse older versions of the documentation - down to v3 - on [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/tree/staging/reference)** - just type `T` or click `Find file` and start typing a cmdlet / conceptual help-topic name.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `Export-CSV` adds the quotes regardless of the type. Probably the only way you can do is to load the file again and use a *regex* to remove those quotes:

```
(get-ChildItem -Path '*.txt').name | ForEach-Object { 
    Import-Csv -Path $_ -Delimiter "`t" | 
    Select-Object -Property Date,Value1 | 
    Export-Csv "out\$_" 
    (Get-Content $_) -replace ',"(\d+),(\d+)"$', ',$1.$2'  | Set-Content "out\$_"
}
```

**Note:** You may want to set the `-Encoding` for the `Set-Content` cmdlet!

Comment: this gives me lines linke this "22.07.2016",8,47 ... not what I had expected, because 8,47 will be interpreted as two columns

Comment: you should also change the Get-Content/Set-Content $_ to out\$_ ... because I just wiped my input files on my PC :) ... and now I'll have to wait till Monday to get a new copy in the office.

Comment: uppps, sorry about that :p

Comment: As an aside, if that folder was indexed just right click on it and choose Restore Previous Versions.